# iphone : NSXMLParser fails to identify HTML special entity &amp;

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, nsxmlparser, entities

I simply cannot get NSXMLParser to recognize &

here is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>
     <myURL>http://www.mywebsite.com/info?id=32&amp;page=5</myURL>>
 </root>
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
-(void)getXml {
 NSURL *xmlurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/myxml.xml"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlurl];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];
[xmlParser release];
[dataurl release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {

NSLog(@"Parser Error: %@", parseError);

}

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser validationErrorOccurred:(NSError *)validError {

NSLog(@"Parser validation Error: %@", validError);


}


- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog(@"Parser started");


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

NSLog(@"Found key: %@", elementName);


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

NSLog(@"Found Element: %@", string);


}


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog("done"):

}
```

Here is my output:

```
 Found key: root
 Found key: myURL
 Found element: http://www.mywebsite.com/info?id=32
 Found element: page=5
 Found element: 
 Found key: myURL
```

The parser is not recognizing the & correctly and is splitting up my url.
I have seen many Stack questions on this issue but none of them have helped and I have read the Apple docs on NSXMLParser as well. Am I missing something here?

I am building with iOS 5.0 to an iPhone 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [NSXMLParserDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3afoundCharacters%3a):

> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

So the usual pattern of usage is to keep appending to a temporary string until the end of the element is reached:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *tempString;
```

.m

```
@synthesize tempString;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    self.tempString = @"";
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.tempString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    // do something with self.tempString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, this is a great insight into the parser process but there were problems using it, maybe due to the features of Xcode 4.5.1

It turned out that assigning a NSString like @"" to a NSMutableString makes it immutable.  Instead to set the starting value for the tempString I've had to use

```
self.tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @""];
```

and the parser:foundCharacters method becomes

```
 - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
[self.tempString  appendString:string];
currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString*) [self.tempString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

But that's one problem solved.  Thanks.

Comment: what is currentNodeContent?